# The file in python (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append')

Tags: python

```
`File = input("Please enter the name for your txt. file: ")

fileName = (File + ".txt")
WRITE = "w"
APPEND = "a"

file = []
name = " "
while name != "DONE" :
    name = input("Please enter the guest name (Enter DONE if there is no   more names) : ").upper()
   fileName.append(name)
fileName.remove("DONE")
print("The guests list in alphabetical order, and it will save in " + fileName + " :")
file.sort()
for U in file :
    print(U)
file = open(fileName, mode = WRITE)
file.write(name)
file.close()
print("file written successfully.")
```

`
I am just practicing to write the file in Python, but something bad happened. Please help me. Thank you.

[The code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcRHu.png)
[The error description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvh6s.png)

Here are still some errors about this :

```
fileName.remove("DONE")
```

Still showing 'str' error.
THANK YOU

Comment: Show us your code, not the output. But I think you want to open a file and write something to it.If this is the case, you can learn from here http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html

Comment: bring the code to your question

Comment: You can't use `.append` on strings. You want something like `fileName += name`. Also, post the code as text, not an image. You can click "edit" to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You try to `append` to string which is not correct in Python, instead try:

```
filename += 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to build a list of names. Start with a list:

```
guests = []
```

and then append the values provided by your user:

```
while name is not "Done":
    prompt = "Please input the name of the next guest, or 'Done'."
    guests.append(input(prompt).upper())
```

then you can sort that list and write the values to the file. (which you seem to have a handle on)

Appending the guests' names to fileName, or concatenating them onto it, wouldn't make a lot of sense. You'd end up with something like "data.txtJOEBOBJANELINDA" which would do you no good at all.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. I add the code here, and please add some more comments. THANKS YOU!